# Proof of quadratic inequality using AM-GM

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Proof of quadratic inequality using AM-GM

Comment: I tried to insert part of the equation in - putting in x^2 and y^2 led to me to finding that x>y using quadratic factorisation... But I'm not exactly sure that would help.

Comment: I'm just not sure how I'm meant to use the x^2 * y^2 with the AM-GM formula.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** Expand $(xy-2)^2\ge0$ and $(x-y)^2\ge0$.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'm assuming that must be sufficient to prove the inequality. In terms of solving that then, how would I solve for the variables? I tried to square root both sides, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Since the inequality is $(xy-2)^2+(x-y)^2\ge0$, for equality, both expressions must be $0$. That is $xy=2$ and $x=y$. In other words, $x=y=\pm\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 3):

$x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+4-6xy=x^2y^2+(x-y)^2+4-4xy=(xy-2)^2+(x-y)^2\geq 0.$

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering if you knew how to solve the equality from the last equation you suggested?

Comment: We have equality iff $xy-2=0=x-y$ iff  $(x=y\land x^2=xy=2)$ iff $x=y=\pm \sqrt 2.$

Comment: Oh right.. Should've noticed that.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

we have to show that $$x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+4-6xy\geq 0$$ dividing by $x^2+1$ gives
$$y^2-\frac{6xy}{x^2+1}+\frac{4+x^2}{x^2+1}\geq 0$$ this is equivalent to
$$\left(y-\frac{3x}{x^2+1}\right)^2+\frac{(4+x^2)(x^2+1)-9x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\geq 0$$
and this is equivalent to $$\left(y-\frac{3x}{x^2+1}\right)^{ 2 }+\frac{(x^2-2)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\geq 0$$
which is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already written down a formal solution for this question using the methods listed below (quadratic factorisation), would that still be correct?